# Create an always-on-top alert on Android from a Service

Tags: android

I've been trying for weeks to find a proper solution to this problem, but I still couldn't find anything.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to create an alert dialog box from a running service (that monitors for some event). The alert dialog should always appear on top of everything else, even if the phone is locked. I'm looking for something similar to what happens when someone calls you, or when an alarm clock goes off.

The best solution I've found was the following:

```
WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager)
    mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)     
mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
mView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_alert, null);
mLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0, 0,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
    PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
mWindowManager.addView(mView, mLayoutParams);
```

And in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

The problem is that if I use the `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`, then the dialog is always shown as I wanted, but I cannot receive any touch events on the buttons I have in the view. On the other hand, if I use `TYPE_PRIORITY_PHONE`, then I do receive all touch events - but the alert isn't shown above the lock screen.